# ldapsearch show member entries without CN

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am using *ldapsearch* on a debian 9 Linux box to query a MS Active Directory. I would like to query/find all users in my group "mygroupname".
The command

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -xWLLL -D "myaccount" -h mydomain -b "ou=user,dc=mydc,dc=com" "cn=mygroupname" member
```

has the following output:

```
dn: CN=mygroupname,OU=user,DC=mydc,DC=com
member: CN=Paula Normal,OU=whatever,OU=...,OU=...,OU=...,DC=mydc,DC=com
member:: Q049QmV0dGluYSBUw7Zs...................9nbmUsT1U9RGV1dHNjwdGEsREM9Y29t
member: CN=Peter Testman,OU=whatever2,OU=...,OU=...,OU=...,DC=mydc,DC=com
...
```

I compared the output with the AD-GUI. The the second entry should be another valid user, but the output is unexpected and unreadable. The CN,OU,DC information is missing. I found out that the strange entries are valid, but are base64-encoded.

Where is the fault? Is there any corruption in the AD? Is my query command wrong? Why are some entries base64-encoded. How to get the right output?

Comment: Could be a legacy member.  Try comparing the output of `repadmin /showobmeta DCNAME "DNOfGroup"`

Comment: With repadmin /showobjmeta localhost "cn=mygroupname,ou....." I see entries with legacy, "present" and with "not present" marked. (showobjmeta not showobmeta). However I cannot follow you yet. What does it mean?

Comment: Is the unreadable member a legacy member? Legacy means it was a member before Windows Server 2003 when Linked Value Replication was introduced. Removing/readding the member converts it from a legacy member to a normal member.

Comment: BTW: You should edit your question and trim the base64-encoded value, what you call strange member entry, because it's a privacy violation.

Answer (score 0):

Your command-line

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -xWLLL -D "myaccount" -h mydomain -b "ou=user,dc=mydc,dc=com" "cn=mygroupname" member
```

explicitly limits the attributes requested in the search to *member*.

Simply try add the wanted attribute names as additional command-line args:

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -xWLLL -D "myaccount" -h mydomain -b "ou=user,dc=mydc,dc=com" "cn=mygroupname" cn ou o member
```

See also: [ldapsearch(1)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldapsearch)

Furthermore you should learn about LDIF syntax (see [RFC 2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849)) which is supposed to be ASCII-clean. The two double-colons after the attribute type name means that the value was base-encoded, e.g. because of NON-ASCII char in a name. Use a decent LDIF module to decode *ldapsearch* output or better use an LDAP module for your favourite scripting language.

Comment: no, it doesn`t change the strange member entries. I guess it must be related to Gregs comment.

Comment: You have two problems. I've edited my answer to also address the 2nd one.

Comment: The first point is not an issue. The output is correct, but the second point explains the strange output and points to a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710483/how-to-stop-ldapsearch1-from-base64-encoding-userpassword-and-other-attributes was a constructive hint. Would you like to edit your answer?

Comment: My strong recommendation is to use a decent LDAP module for your favourite scripting language instead of weird and unmaintainable perl/awk/sed/whatever constructs seen in the wild. => No, I deliberately won't edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the unexpected output is a NON-ASCII char in the cn-name.
The line starting with "member:: " indicates a base64-encoded value, which can be decoded (by e.g. `echo "$value"  | base64 -d -`)

The  search  results  of ldapsearch are  displayed using an extended version of LDIF.

> LDIF syntax (see [RFC 2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849)) is supposed to be ASCII-clean.

A quick workaround to receive a readable output could be made by using a wrapper like

```
myldapsearch() { ldapsearch $* | perl -MMIME::Base64 -n -00 -e 's/\n +//g;s/(?<=:: )(\S+)/decode_base64($1)/eg;print'; }
```

Seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710483/how-to-stop-ldapsearch1-from-base64-encoding-userpassword-and-other-attributes) question.